# How to get access from Event store?

Tags: ios, ios7

How to get access from Event store? It is always saying Access Denied.

Here my code:

```
if (_eventStore==nil)  //Events store Object
{
     _eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc]init];
     [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityMaskReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
     if (!granted)
            NSLog(@"Access Denied");
      }];
}
else
{
    [self createReminder]; //Function to create reminder
}
```

I want to create a reminder using `EKRemainder` class but it is showing access is denied.  How to get access from EKRemainder?

Comment: Does your app is allowed to access Reminder/Calendar? In first try a pop-up should appear. You can change the authorization in Settings.app

Comment: No, no pop is coming in my app Larne.  Am is missing anything in my code? And also, in setting->privacy "App that have requested access will appear here" message only displaying... Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

please see the [Apple demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160) for the calendar event

Answer (score 0):

You should replace "EKEntityMaskReminder with "EKEntityTypeReminder" like this

```
    [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
}
```

Hope this helps.